# Why float value auto incremented while sysout

Tags: java, primitive-types

In my application, I am using float value to hold customer score. And as per the requirement, the score may have only 5 decimal digits  before the points  and three digits after the points.

For example : 99999.999

But, I did not understand the strange behavior while printing float values using sysout.

Refer sample code below for more details :

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float f1 = 9999.999f;
        System.out.println(f1);

        float f2 = 99999.999f;
        System.out.println(f2);
    }
}
```

And the Output is :

```
9999.999
100000.0
```

Here, why the value "99999.999" got auto incremented to "100000.0" while doing using sysout ?
And why the same thing was not happened while using value of four decimal digits before the point i.e "9999.999" ?

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: floats don't have that level of precision.

Comment: Your question is rather about how many decimal places can a float have without losing precison when going back and forth in base conversion. Check this out > [https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/215065/can-anyone-explain-representation-of-float-in-memory](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/215065/can-anyone-explain-representation-of-float-in-memory)

Answer (score 3):

From java specifications:

> float: The float data type is a single-precision 32-bit IEEE 754
>   floating point. Its range of values is beyond the scope of this
>   discussion, but is specified in the Floating-Point Types, Formats, and
>   Values section of the Java Language Specification. As with the
>   recommendations for byte and short, use a float (instead of double) if
>   you need to save memory in large arrays of floating point numbers.
>   This data type should never be used for precise values, such as
>   currency. For that, you will need to use the java.math.BigDecimal
>   class instead. Numbers and Strings covers BigDecimal and other useful
>   classes provided by the Java platform.

To conclude if you want to save memory and you don't care about precission use float otherwise use double.
More info here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

I suggest to use [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)
and use the [setScale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int)) method for your case.

Answer (score 3):

`float` uses **24-bit** for its "mantissa" which holds all the significant digits.This means floats are usually good up to `7` significant digits. Your number is `99999.999f` which has `8` significant digits.so you will lose precision after `7` digits and get this kind of errors past `7` digits.

If you try to put : `double f2 = 99999.999;`

You will get the right result because double uses **53-bit** for it "mantissa" so it can hold about 16 digits accurately.